# JS alert()'s block other must-run threads

Tags: javascript, multithreading

I have a JS client application, which as a part of its functionality, sends "heartbeats" every second to the server.

The "heartbeats" are simple AJAX calls, and if the server does not get any heartbeat for X seconds, it refuses to any future request from the client. Hence, the heartbeats engine in the client must always be on and must not be stopped during the runtime.

The problem is that the alert messages stop the heartbeat engine (until the user accepts the message). If the user waited more than X seconds with accepting the message, than the server refuses to server the client anymore...

This is my heartbeat function:

```
function send_heartbeat_to_server() {
    var successFunc = function(jsonObj) {
        // do something
    }
    var errorFunc = function(statusCode, message) {
        // do something
    }
    var additionalData = {'some-key' : 'some-value'};
    corsAjaxCall("http://" + client_url + "/heartbeat", additionalData, successFunc, errorFunc);

    // Calling the heartbeat engine again and again every second...
    setTimeout(send_heartbeat_to_server, 1000);
}

// Calling the heartbeat engine for the first time
send_heartbeat_to_server();
```

How can I prevent the function `send_heartbeat_to_server()` from stopping when an alert message is shown?

Comment: well, then why use `alert` ?

Comment: You really should avoid using `alert`, for this and other problems.

Comment: The recommended solution is just not using `alert`? It might be possible to show a pop-up div, which looks like an `alert` message, which will not stop the threads?

Comment: I'll be glad of you write these recommendations as answers. I will take your advice and will not use alert anymore